# Open close function?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have found a function on Ozzu.com that fits my needs only problem is I do not grab whats happening 100%. Could you give me a run down of whats happening here:

```
function toggle(id) {
  var e = document.getElementById(id);

  if (e.style.display == '')
    e.style.display = 'none';
  else
    e.style.display = '';
}
```

and then this goes in the source page:

```
<a href="#" onclick="toggle('content')">Toggle</a>
```

I am confused on what the if/else is actually doing to make this work

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.style

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're modifying the CSS `display` property of the HTML element with ID "content", onclick, via JavaScript.  Every time you call the `toggle` function, it does essentially the following:

```
if (document.getElementById("content").style.display == '') {
  document.getElementById("content").style.display = 'none';
} else {
  document.getElementById("content").style.display = '';
}
```

If you set the `display` property to `'none'`, the HTML element with ID "content" will not be rendered.  If you set it to empty string (`""`), it will use the default value for that HTML element (which is visible in all cases).

Comment: Let me see if I understand this line 1 says if the content (div in this case)style.display is equal to nothing or not set. Line 2 than sets the style.display to "none". ELSE turns off the style.display to none so if will show what ever was in the context id?

Comment: The `display` property being empty string (`""`) means the div is visible.  The `if` says "if the div is currently visible, then make it invisible."  The else equates to "if the div is not currently visible, then make it visible."

Comment: Thank you I think I am grasping it now.

Answer (score 1):

A onclick event is added to the  node. So that when you click on it, it will call `toggle` and it will also pass the argument `content`.

- The function `toggle` receives one argument, which is used as the ID.
- Using this ID, it will then get the elemnt from the dom.
- With the element saved to `e`, it then checks the style attributes, to see what the "display" property is set to.
- If the property is an empty string (meaning not set), then it sets it to display none. Likewise, if it is already set to display none, then it will set it to blank. (Thus showing it again).

Just as a side note, this is actually not a very good way of doing it, because it assumes that elements have not had their display setting changed.

Answer (score 1):

It is however better to do this

```
function toggle(id) {
  var e = document.getElementById(id);
  e.style.display = (e.style.display == '')?'none':''; // I prefer a ternary here
  return false; // cancel the click !
}


<a href="#" onclick="return toggle('content')">Toggle</a>
```

or unobtrusively:

```
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById('toggleLink').onclick=function() {
    var e = document.getElementById('content');
    e.style.display = (e.style.display == '')?'none':''; // I prefer a ternary here
    return false; // cancel the click !
  }
}


<a href="#" id="toggleLink"">Toggle</a>
```

Comment: Could you explain why these are better, and what the ternary does? Much thanks

Comment: the return false is very important to stop the page from trying to reload. The ternary is just shorthand for what you did already.